# Can I change the key bindings on the free version of CodeRush Express for Visual Studio?

Tags: devexpress, coderush

Note: I've tried posting on the coderush/devexpress forums and as is usual for that kind of thing, received no response. Hopefully some SO users use coderush express and can possibly help?

Hi. I've just installed the free CodeRush XPress addon, and it looks nice, however I can't figure out how to change the key bindings! I find Ctrl+Alt+F awkward to hit, and Shift+Enter conflicts with an existing keybinding I have had setup for the last 3 years so am really resistant to CodeRush overwriting it.

Am I just being dumb and missing something really obvious or is "change keybindings" not a feature of the free version?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The DevExpress guys responded. It's Ctrl+Shift+Alt+O to bring up the options. Brilliant

Comment: incredible. Defently don't use the default options window!