# Numeric Keypad + Key selects text in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

This really isn't programming per se, but is related to Visual Studio..

Anytime I use the + key on my numeric keypad, it increases the current selection.  The +/= key works properly.  This is only affecting Visual Studio as well..

I checked the Regional settings, and it's set properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that's the default behaviour for [Coderush](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/), do you have it or the free express edition installed?

If you do it has its own keyboard shortcut settings in its options dialog. You'll need to delete the binding from there to get the key back to normal.

Comment: I think so.. I installed it a while back, but never noticed it.  is there a way to disable that option?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Coderush's keybindings are separate to the standard Visual Studio ones, so you need to look in its own settings window.

Comment: Maybe I'm blind, but I'm not seeing an options dialog anywhere... I have CodeRush Express

Comment: Ah, I have the full version, but a quick search of this very site says that Ctrl+Shift+Alt+O is the highly intuitive keyboard command to bring up the options for the express version. From here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459656/can-i-change-the-key-bindings-on-the-free-version-of-coderush-express-for-visual